# Gerando numero aleatório na linguagem C

Tags: c, random

Vamos supor que eu tenho uma array vazia de tamanho 8.

`int A[8];`

E então eu pretendo preenchê-la com valores aleatórios cujo eu teria uma função parecida com a `rand();`
Porém, eu chamo a `rand()` para cada elemento da array, sendo assim todos os elementos tem o mesmo valor.

Até agora eu tenho essa função:

```
int randInt(int intMax)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    return rand() % (intMax+1);
}
```

No caso ela retornaria o mesmo valor caso eu chamasse essa função por duas ou mais vezes, pois ela está relacionada ao tempo.
Minha dúvida seria como posso implementar uma função que retornasse um valor aleatório mesmo chamando-a duas ou mais vezes?

Comment: `srand` deve ser executado uma única vez no tempo de vida da aplicação, com exceção quando se deseja gerar a mesma sequência de números aleatórios ou sequências específicas, que não é o seu caso. Não vi nenhuma resposta dizer isto explicitamente. Por isso, normalmente, `srand` é chamado logo na inicialização da aplicação, dentro do próprio `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente utilizar o trecho abaixo

```
int rand[8];
int range;
srand(time(NULL));
range = (1000 - 1) + 1; 

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
  rand[i] = rand() % range + 1;
}
```

Comment: Eu consegui da um jeito aqui, mas vlw

Answer (score 3):

Use a função `srand(time(NULL));` antes de chamar a função rand, ela serve para recarregar os valores que serão gerados pelo rand.

**exemplo:**

```
srand(time(NULL));
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
  rand[i] = rand() % range + 1;
}
```

**Tradução da descrição da função**

> A função srand ()  define seu argumento como a semente para uma nova
>   seqüência
>           de inteiros pseudo-aleatórios a ser devolvido pela rand(). estas sequências
>           são repetíveis chamando srand() com o mesmo valor de semente.