# Função rand() não retorna números aleatórios. C++

Tags: c++, random

Tenho uma função que precisa gerar, em uma parte específica, um número aleatório para fazer um determinada tarefa. Mas sempre que o programa entra nessa função, o número gerado não muda, ficando sempre em zero. Segue o código:

```
do{ // Garante que seja escolhido um item que ainda nao esteja na mochila
        srand( (unsigned) time (NULL) );    // Gera um numero aleatorio, usado para selecionar um item qualquer na lista de itens disponiveis
        item_position = rand() % num_items;
        printf("item_position: %d", item_position);

        j = 0;
        while(j < index_items->size()) 
        {
            printf("Item escolhido: %d \n\n\n", item_position);
            if(item_position == index_items->at(j)) // Verifica se o item escolhido aleatoriamente ja nao esta na mochila
                itens_repetidos += 1;               //Dessa forma, evita repeticoes dentro da mochila
            j++;
        }
    }while(itens_repetidos != 0);
```

Como visto no código, utilizo as funções srand e rand para gerar o número. O que pode estar errado?

Comment: O `srand` deve ser chamado apenas uma vez no início do programa, não dentro do looping `do`. Relacionado: [Gerando numero aleatório na linguagem C](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64838/gerando-numero-aleat%C3%B3rio-na-linguagem-c/64902)

Comment: Sugiro gerar alguns números aleatórios e confirmar se a função rand() retorna um valor entre 0 e 1 ou número inteiro. Concordo com @Gomiero, use srand somente para inicializar, só 1x no programa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você colocou os 2 includes necessários para gerar os números?
`#include<stdlib.h>` e `#include<time.h>`.
A variável num_itens tem que ter um valor também.
Substitua o `srand( (unsigned) time (NULL) )` por `srand(time(0))` e coloque esta linha fora do loop (comando `do - while`)
Isso resolve seu problema.
Abraço